# How to package shared internal Python module with wheel?

Tags: python, deployment, packaging, python-wheel

We have a separate Python package (shared modules) that we build ourselves which is stored in our internal git repository. We need to use this package in another Python project/application.

In a development setting, we can run `pip install -e <module/path>` and the module can then be used in other Python applications.

How do I tell `wheel` to install these internal shared modules when we are deploying it?

Comment: Have you looked at https://hynek.me/articles/sharing-your-labor-of-love-pypi-quick-and-dirty/ and the wheels website http://pythonwheels.com/ yet?

Comment: @pcurry any specific part? I need wheel to checkout the library from git and package it from there.

Comment: I'm not sure, I haven't used wheel.  I've mostly written RPMs, which did the checkout and then ran setup.py.